# Passing array from aspx.cs to xaml.cs

Tags: c#, asp.net, silverlight

Is there a way to pass an array or List<> from the aspx.cs to xaml.cs?

Answer (score 2):

the only way to pass data from your aspx hosting the control to your silverlight control is using **[InitParams](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.startupeventargs.initparams%28VS.95%29.aspx)** which is a dictionary. try concating your string array using some predefied separator which you set on the InitParams and split again in the silverlight control.

**update**

```
string data = string.Join("[SEP]", strList);
string InitParams = "data=" + data;
```

you can embed this InitParams string into your object tag.
pass this via InitParams. in your silverlight application

```
string[] data = e.InitParams["data"].Split("[SEP]");
```

Comment: @vinay i figured out how to pass single variables then parse them on the xaml.cs side, but how do you send a list/array or object?

Comment: @vinay awesome i'll try it out. I'm assuming that string.Join works when you pass in a List<double> also?

Comment: Do you know how to do this with a List<double>?

Comment: InitParams can only take strings so might have to convert your List<double> to list<string> in aspx and convert it back in xaml

Comment: @vinay interesting. why is your second portion of code in an event handler? if so, what is the event handler you're calling? thx

Comment: e is application start up event args in your silverlight application